# How to stop an API connection using Python

Tags: python, tiktok

I wrote this code to determine whether a TikTok live video is (live now) or (ended) one.

After getting the result (live now or not), it keeps running and giving the result... I want to stop the API connection after having the result for one time.

For example: `client.stop()` but I can't where to type that...

Documentation https://github.com/isaackogan/TikTokLive

Using the following code:

```
from TikTokLive import TikTokLiveClient
from TikTokLive.types.events import ViewerCountUpdateEvent
from TikTokLive.types.errors import FailedConnection


class TikTok:
    """
    This class is to determine whether a TikTok live video is (live now) or (ended) one.
    """

    @staticmethod
    def is_live(url):
        """
        This method will count the viewers and decide whether it is a current live or not.
        """
        client: TikTokLiveClient = TikTokLiveClient(
            unique_id=url, **(
                {"fetch_room_info_on_connect": True}
            )
        )

        @client.on("viewer_count_update")
        async def on_connect(event: ViewerCountUpdateEvent):
            # since we have views, so it is live!
            print("The live is running now.")

        try:
            client.run()

        except FailedConnection:
            # if there is no views, it will gives error, so I handled that here.
            print("The video is no longer live.")

# pass the live video username.
is_livestream = TikTok.is_live(url="radwanghaddar")
```

Comment: By the way, your is_live function doesn't return anything, so that variable will be None

Comment: You'd call stop when you're done using the client, though (after is_live)

Comment: @OneCricketeer It keeps giving the result. it is not stopping :(

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Please edit your question to show where you're trying to close the client

Comment: @OneCricketeer I did the editing. I hope it's clear now. If you try it on your local you may find how it is running. but you need to do `pip install TikTokLive`

Comment: I still don't see `client.stop()` in your question. Also, I don't think "view count" really determines if something is live streaming or not. Perhaps you should check if the view count hits zero? A failed connection could also just mean you cannot connect to TikTok at all, not that it is "not live"